# Disable automatic escaping of double quotes inside a JSON object?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

```
update table set column = json_insert(column, '$.newKey', OUTPUT)
```

I am inserting the value of the JSON string below as a value to **OUTPUT** variable above.

```
select json_object('key1', '{"key11": "value11", "key12": "value12"}',
                   'key2', '{"key21": "value21", "key22": "value22"}');
```

Running this mysql snippet results to:

```
{
  "key1": "{\"key11\": \"value11\", \"key12\": \"value12\"}",
  "key2": "{\"key21\": \"value21\", \"key22\": \"value22\"}"
}
```

How should I set the value of `key1` and `key2` such that the value will be saved as is, without the backslashes, i.e.:

```
{
   "key1": {"key11": "value11", "key12": "value12"},
   "key2": {"key21": "value21", "key22": "value22"}
}
```

I tried using JSON_OBJECT again in the value part but the result still adds the backslashes.

```
select JSON_OBJECT('key1', JSON_OBJECT('key11', 'value11', 'key12': 'value12'),
                  ('key2', JSON_OBJECT('key21', 'value21', 'key22': 'value22')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The code that builds the JSON is incorrect. Build the JSON using nested `JSON_OBJECT` calls:

```
select json_object(
    'key1', json_object(
        'key11', 'value11',
        'key12', 'value12'
    ),
    'key2', json_object(
        'key21', 'value21',
        'key22', 'value22'
    )
)
```

The result (after pretty-printing) would be:

```js
{
    "key1": {
        "key11": "value11",
        "key12": "value12"
    },
    "key2": {
        "key21": "value21",
        "key22": "value22"
    }
}
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f58345edaa419b55c612651f042650ff)

Comment: `update table set column=JSON_INSERT(column, '$.newKey', json_object(
    'key1', json_object('key11', 'value11', 'key12', 'value12'),
    'key2', json_object('key21', 'value21', 'key22', 'value22')
))`


Doing this still escapes the double quote. :(

Comment: Nope. The generated JSON is correct (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a5bd5b7baf91467b40ffdb931d65c9d6). Something else is wrong. Perhaps (i) the newKey already exists with bad data (ii) `json_insert` does not overwrite existing keys.

Comment: Thank you, something was wrong with the data indeed.